# Inserting well over 100,000 records into SQLite

Tags: xml, database, apache-flex, sqlite, air

I have a database that needs to be updated periodically.  My employer wants to keep a base instance of it in MS Access, and update one in a local SQLite table.

I've been able to grab all of the data out of the MS Access table (into XML), but when I try to insert it into the SQLite table, I get the error that there are too many terms in the compound select statement.

I know that SQLite limit compound select inserts to 500, but this database is over 150,000 rows.  I'm at a loss for how to get the data moved over.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Here is the code that I was trying to use:

```
var sqlItem:String="INSERT INTO items (itemID,barcode,desc,brandNum,size,units,multQty,multPrice,price,brand,cat01,catSub,cost,srp,lastPriceChangeDate,lastScanDate,addDate,chgDate) ";
for each(var i:XML in itemList.item){
    sqlItem=sqlItem+"SELECT "+
    parseInt(i.itemID,10)+","+
    parseInt(i.barcode,10)+","+
    "\""+i.description+"\","+
    parseInt(i.brandNum,10)+","+
    "\""+i.size+"\","+
    "\""+i.units+"\","+
    parseInt(i.multQty,10)+","+
    "\""+i.multPrice+"\","+
    "\""+i.price+"\","+
    "\""+i.brand+"\","+
    "\""+i.cat01+"\","+
    "\""+i.catSub+"\","+
    "\""+i.cost+"\","+
    "\""+i.srp+"\","+
    "\""+i.lastPriceChangeDate+"\","+
    "\""+i.lastScanDate+"\","+
    "\""+i.addDate+"\","+
    "\""+i.chgDate+"\""+
    " UNION ";
}
sqlItem=sqlItem.substring(0,sqlItem.length-7);
itemStmt.text=sqlItem;
try{
    itemStmt.execute();
}catch(error:SQLError){
    trace("Update USER Database - ERROR: "+error.detailID +" - "+error.details );
}
```

Here is an example of the XML that I am reading into the database:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <itemID>1234</itemID>
        <barcode>01111111111111</barcode>
        <description>Product Description</description>
        <brandNum>1</brandNum>
        <size>1</size>
        <units>oz.</units>
        <multQty>1</multQty>
        <multPrice>0.85</multPrice>
        <price>0.85</price>
        <brand>Product Brand</brand>
        <cat01>Product Category</cat01>
        <catSub>(none)</catSub>
        <cost>0.10</cost>
        <srp>0.95</srp>
        <lastPriceChangeDate>1/9/2009 3:32:29 PM</lastPriceChangeDate>
        <lastScanDate>1/9/2009 3:32:29 PM<lastScanDate>
        <addDate/>1/9/2009 3:32:29 PM<addDate/>
        <chgDate>1/9/2009 3:32:29 PM</chgDate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <itemID>1234</itemID>
        <barcode>01111111111111</barcode>
        <description>Product Description</description>
        <brandNum>1</brandNum>
        <size>1</size>
        <units>oz.</units>
        <multQty>1</multQty>
        <multPrice>0.85</multPrice>
        <price>0.85</price>
        <brand>Product Brand</brand>
        <cat01>Product Category</cat01>
        <catSub>(none)</catSub>
        <cost>0.10</cost>
        <srp>0.95</srp>
        <lastPriceChangeDate>1/9/2009 3:32:29 PM</lastPriceChangeDate>
        <lastScanDate>1/9/2009 3:32:29 PM<lastScanDate>
        <addDate/>1/9/2009 3:32:29 PM<addDate/>
        <chgDate>1/9/2009 3:32:29 PM</chgDate>
    </item>
</items>
```

Comment: IS this as simple as "Loop over the source data with a step of 500"?

Comment: It probably could be, but I'm not sure how I could loop through the XML data every 500 records.  I had thought about trying something like that, but I was not successful at getting it for loop properly...

Comment: Once you get an XMLListCollection of your item Elements; just use a for loop and increment the counter variable, like this: counter+= 500 in each iteration .  That counter is, in essence, the first element of the insert statement.

Comment: Thanks Flextras, that worked...  I tried something similar, but couldn't get it to work, yesterday.  I just stuck a counter inside the for each loop to execute the query every 495 records.  Thanks for the assist...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution it works!!! I have tested this solution even in Web Sql DB based on sqlite

select sqlite_version()

### 3.6.19

```
INSERT INTO items (val)  
select * from
(select 1  val  union all
 select 2   val union all
 select 3   val union all
 select 4   val union all
 ...
 select 500 val
)
union all
select * from
(select 501  val    union all
 select 502 val union all
 select 503 val union all
 select 504 val union all
 ...
 select 1000    val
)
union all
select * from
(select 1001  val   union all
 select 1002    val union all
 select 1003    val union all
 select 1004    val union all
 ...
 select 1500    val
)
...
```